# WPF ListBox with CheckBoxes: select the checkbox before checking it

Tags: wpf, xaml

**Problem**:

I have a Listbox, in that Listbox are Checkboxes. On the first click the Checkbox is selected and checked. On the second click the checkbox only gets set. One can reselect a different Checkbox using the arrow keys. My goal is, that the checkbox gets selected first and then checked afterwards (clicking again on it) thus removing the need for Arrow keys.

**Goal**:

- Select the Item on first click
- Check the Checkbox on second click

**The Code**:

```
<ListBox Name="Terminals" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTerminals, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{Binding DisplayColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

disable click registration on CheckBox via binding `IsHitTestVisible` property to selection state of ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBox Name="Terminals" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTerminals, Mode=OneWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" 
                      IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                      Foreground="{Binding DisplayColor}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

this way the first click will only select ListBoxItem and checkboxes can be checked/unchecked by second click

---

after items are added to ListBox, the visual tree is the following:

```
ListBox
 --ListBoxItem
   --CheckBox
 --ListBoxItem
   --CheckBox
 --ListBoxItem
   --CheckBox
```

When user click on ListBoxItem, it gets selected (IsSelected=true). When user click on CheckBox, it gets checked or unchecked. But if `IsHitTestVisible` set to false, click on element will not be registered. Since check/uncheck should work only for selected items, we can create binding between CheckBox.IsHitTestVisible and parent ListBoxItem.IsSelected to achieve such effect